# How to register schema extension for "Chat" resource type in graph api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365

I am trying to add a new property to the Chat resource type in MS graph using schemaExtention, however when I try to register schema extension for a chat resource type I get an error

HTTP Post - https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/schemaExtensions

Body -

```
{
  "id": "<extensionId>",
  "description": "<extensionDescription>",
  "targetTypes": [
    "Chat"
  ],
  "properties": [
    {
      "name": "<customPropertyName>",
      "type": "String"
    }
  ]
}
```

Error -

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Argument targetType chat is invalid.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2023-06-21T12:39:41",
            "request-id": "<request-id>",
            "client-request-id": "<client-request-id>"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Schema extensions are not supported by `chat` resource type.

Supported resource types are `user`, `group`, `administrativeUnit`, `application`, `contact`, `device`, `event`, `message`, `organization` and `post`.

Documentation:

[schemaExtension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/schemaextension?view=graph-rest-1.0#:%7E:text=following%20resource%20types)